# codimension of the zero set of a polynomial in several variables and their conjugates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f(z_1,\overline{z_1},\dots,z_n,\overline{z_n})$ be a polynomial in $n$ variables and their complex conjugates. Does set set
$$V = \{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \mathbb{C^n} \mid f(z_1,\overline{z_1},\dots,z_n,\overline{z_n})=0\}$$
have codimension one in $\mathbb{C}^n$? In $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? Could anyone point me towards a reference I could cite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything can happen. Writing $z_j=x_j+iy_j$ for real $x_j$ and $y_j$, we can express $x_j$ and $y_j$ as polynomials in $z_j$ and $\overline{z_j}$: $x_j=\frac{z_j+\overline{z_j}}{2}$ and $x_y=\frac{z_j-\overline{z_j}}{2i}$. From separating real and imaginary parts, this means we can get up to two real polynomials in the $x_j$ and $y_j$. But this means we can get any dimension of vanishing set we want: consider the polynomial $$(\sum_{j=1}^r x_j^2)+(\sum_{j=1}^s y_j^2)$$ which cuts out a subset of codimension $r+s$.

Comment: But $\operatorname{codim}(V) = 0$ only if $f$ is trivial, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.